# Program that inputs a number and then prints the set bits of that number with the bit integer displayed next to it

Tags: c, loops, printing, binary, binary-search

for example, if I enter 12, I want to get 81 41 as the set bits in 12 are 1100

This is what I have for now, I do not think I am implementing the for loop correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>
void bin(unsigned n)
{
    char list[6]; 
    int x = 0, y = 1;
    /* step 1 */
    if (n > 1)
        bin(n / 2);
 
    /* step 2 */
    list[x] = n % 2;
    x++;
    /*for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",list[i]);
    }*/
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          if(list[i] == 1 && i == 5) {
           printf("32%i",y);
          }
          if(list[i] == 1 && i == 4) {
             printf("16%i",y);
          }
          if(list[i] == 1 && i == 3) {
             printf("8%i",y);
          }
          if(list[i] == 1 && i == 2) {
             printf("4%i",y);
          }
          if(list[i] == 1 && i == 1) {
             printf("2%i",y);
          }
          if(list[i] == 1 && i == 0) {
             printf("1%i",y);
          }
}
}
```

I checked that I was correctly storing the bytes in the array, and it outputted correctly, but when I try to look for them one at a time in a loop, it seems to get stuck on the 32 bit integer, so for 12, it would print 321 321

Comment: Are you sure about `list[i] = 1` as a condition? Doesn't your compiler complain about that? And due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) `list[i] = 1 && i == 5` is actually `list[i] = (1 && i == 5)` which is unlikely what you want.

Comment: I fixed that... now, for instance, when I enter 12, I get 11 11. seems like it didnt fix the issue

Comment: I recommend that you use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Answer (score 0):

This program has [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) from accessing uninitialized values of `list`. I'm going to refactor this code so its easier to talk about, but know this refactored code is still incorrect.

`x` is always `0`. `y` is always `1`. `x++` has no effect. This function can be rewritten as:

```
void bin(unsigned n)
{
    char list[6];

    if (n > 1)
        bin(n / 2);

    list[0] = n % 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (list[i] == 1) {
            switch (i) {
                case 5: printf("321"); break;
                case 4: printf("161"); break;
                case 3: printf("81"); break;
                case 2: printf("41"); break;
                case 1: printf("21"); break;
                case 0: printf("11"); break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are some problems here.

Firstly, `list` is not shared between calls to `bin`, nor are any other variables.

In every call to `bin`, only `list[0]` is assigned a value - all others indices contain uninitialized values. You are (un)lucky in that these values are seemingly never `1`.

With your example of `12` as the starting value:

When you initially call `bin(12)`, what happens is:

`bin(12)` calls `bin(6)`, `bin(6)` calls `bin(3)`, `bin(3)` calls `bin(1)`.

Starting from the end and working backwards, in `bin(1)`:

`n = 1`, so `list[0] = n % 2;` assigns `1`. The loop checks each element of `list` for the value `1`, finds it when the index (`i`) equals `0`, and prints `11`.

This is repeated in `bin(3)`, as `3 % 2` is also `1`, and again this result is assigned to the first element of `list`. Again, we print `11`.

In `bin(6)`, `6 % 2` is `0`. The loop finds no elements of `list` that equal `1`. Nothing is printed.

And again, this is repeated in `bin(12)`, as `12 % 2` is `0`. Nothing is printed.

To reiterate, it is pure luck that this program *appears to work*. Accessing `list[1]` through `list[4]` (`i < 5` ensures you never access the last element) in each function call is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). It is generally not worth reasoning about a program once UB has been invoked.

---

When dealing with bits, it would be a good time to use some [bitwise operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic).

Here is a program that more-or-less does what you have described.

It assumes 32-bit `unsigned` (consider using fixed width types from [`<stdint.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) to be more precise).

This program works by repeatedly shifting the bits of our initial value to the right `b` number of places and testing if the rightmost bit is set.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned num = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 42;
    unsigned b = 32;

    while (b--)
        if ((num >> b) & 1)
            printf("%u1 ", 1 << b);

    putchar('\n');
}
```

```
$ ./a.out 12
81 41
```